# This doesn't produce a window and I don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

I am using VPython in my attempt to model a ball bouncing off a wall.

To make my code more elegant, I have decided to use class inheritance to set the dimensions and properties of my objects (at the moment, it's the ball and a wall). After I ran the code, the shell didn't produce any errors, however, it did not produce a window either.

I am fairly new to programming and I am using VPython 2.7 in Wine on Linux Mint 18. I have a feeling that I have missed something obvious but I don't know what it is.

My code so far is as follows:

```
from visual import *

class Obj(object):

def __init__(self, pos, color): #sets the position and color
         self.pos = pos
         self.color = color

class Sphere(Obj):

    def __init__(self, pos, color, radius):
        super(Sphere, self).__init__(pos, color)
        self.radius = radius

class Box(Obj):

    def __init__self, pos, color, radius):
        super(Box, self).__init__(pos, color)
        self.size = size
        self.opacity = opacity


ball1 = Sphere((-5,0,0,), color.orange, 0.25)
wallR = Box((6,0,0), color.cyan, (0.,12,12), 0.3)
```

Comment: I don't see any code related to initializing a window. Could you please post it ? Your current code only deals with the objects you want to draw in your window.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of what you mean by initializing a window?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you never dealt with graphic aspects before, as there is nothing about it in the code you posted. Then it is time to begin !
By default, python works in console mode. To show an actual window, with icons and stuff going across it, you'll need to write it explicitly in your code, using modules like **TKinter** or **pygame**.

I suggest you read the tutorial I found here : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502241-bouncing-ball-simulation/ as it does what you want (with **TKinter**), including the window part. Take a look at it and let's see if you still need help !